# Temp tablespace runs out of space and prompts ORA-01652 when a select is executed

Tags: oracle, query-optimization

I am facing an issue while executing a huge query, where the temp tablespace of the oracle instance runs out of space. At the following link is the query.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96203352/Query/title_block.sql

Size of the Temp tablespace is 30 GB and due to clients concerns I can not extend its space more. Therefore, I tried to reduce sort operations but it all went in vain. Is there anyway to optimize or reduce sorts operations of this query.

At the following link the statistics of the PLAN Table is placed.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96203352/Query/PLAN_TABLE_INFO.txt

As the size of the query and the explain plan is way to large to be posted in this question, therefore I have to share it while using a link. Sorry for the inconvenience.

One more thing I can not remove distinct from the select statement as there is duplication in the data returned.

Please help.

Comment: Is the distinct (and subquery) necessary, and is there any improvement if you don't do that step? Have you considered joining to `iistentry` once and then pivoting (possibly manually to incorporate the column-specific conditions) to get the separate columns?

Comment: I tried that. But no considerable improvement.

Comment: use row_number() analytical function for avoid duplications, i think it would be cheaper than distinct

Comment: i cannot reach the files(dropbox is blocked), are you using with clause in the query?

Comment: Is it an option to create a table instead of a view, and then fill the table with a procedure that manually collects the data with one or more loops?

Comment: Thomas I tried row_number() as well. Using I.id for partitioning and ordered it by r.rev and c.change_number. It was more slower than distinct.

Comment: CarloCe. Please elaborate. What do you mean by manually collects data. :)

Comment: Thomas. I am not using CTEs.

Comment: @BurhanKhalidButt then you should use it, it can reduce the usage of temp space if you organize a few basic complex subquery into WITHs

Comment: and with the above hint you can use a row_number func to reduce the working resultset, even on multiple subquery levels

Comment: Please paste your code & results directly into the question, rather than posting to an outside service like pastebin or Dropbox. The external code can go away at any time, and there is no version control over it like with SO questions. Therefore, future readers may not be able to see the external code and thus this question will be useless or not make much sense. They certainly will not be able to find this question via keyword searching. **StackOverflow is as much about future reference for others as it is about you getting your question answered today.**

Answer (score 0):

The query plan says it all at the very top: all the temp space is being used by the `DISTINCT` operation.  The reason that operation is requiring so much memory is that your query rows are so fat... around 10,000 bytes each!!!

I'm not sure why your query rows are so fat, but one suggestion I would try would be to change your query to do the `DISTINCT` operation and then, in a later step, `CAST` the necessary columns to `VARCHAR2(3999)`.  Logically that shouldn't affect it, but I've seen strange behaviour with `CAST` over the years.  I wouldn't trust it enough not to at least try my suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. I'll try that.